# .NET targeting multiple frameworks in VS2017. How to get IDE to target specific preprocessor directive?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-standard

I am creating a class library and have it targeting multiple frameworks. In this case .NetStandard 2.0 and .Net Framework 4.5. I want to write code specifically for .NET 4.5, but it's always greyed out and I get no intellisense. How to I tell the IDE I want to work on .NET 4.5?

[image]

I see you can change this, but it doesn't change how the IDE reacts (I know this is for running the app, but I thought I'd give it a try):

[image]

It's probably a stupid question, but I can't find anything online about targeting a specific framework in the IDE. Thank you.

Comment: If using different Build configurations, specific defines can be added per configuration.

Comment: This isn't build configuration, as far as I know. It's a targetframework thing. There are no build configurations around it. This is what I am doing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-target-frameworks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

bah. I found it. It's right under the tab of the CS file you are working on:

[image]

I knew it was a stupid question. But I wasted over an hour looking for this setting.

Comment: I was 30 minutes searching for this. Thanks.